# In HTML file, how do I link to a cycript file?

Tags: html, cycript

I tried this in the head section but doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/cycript" charset="utf-8" src="Scripts/cycript.cy"></script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cycript runs standalone on Android and Linux and provides access to Java, but without injection !
Never saw it linked from HTML (src include javascripts).

Comment: I'm using it in an iOS widget, I have all cycript code inside cycript tags and all is fine but the page is getting big, just wondered if it's possible to link it similar to a javascript file.